# do toggle operation onoverlayPanel in.ts

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9

I need to do toggle operation on a element :

```
   <p-overlayPanel #panel>...
```

I must take it in my .ts code:

```
    @ViewChild('panel') someInput: ElementRef;
this.someInput.toggle()
```

and after I don't knwo what I have to do? anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you want to toggle visibility of `p-overlayPanel` element based on events of other input element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get a reference of the overlayPanel component like this

```js
 @ViewChild('panel',{static:true}) panel: OverlayPanel;
```

then you can call toggle or show method but these method require a browser event or target element to align the panel

```js
 @ViewChild('elm',{static:true}) elm: ElementRef;
```

then you can call toggle method like this

```js
 ngOnInit(){
   this.panel.toggle(null,this.elm.nativeElement)
 }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-overlaypanel)